# Spark error "Results not generated" when writing to Snowflake

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spark-structured-streaming

I need help checking whether messages are actually getting written to my Kafka topic.
My docker-compose.yml is as shown below

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
    container_name: Zookeeper 
    ports: 
      - "2181:2181" 
    environment: 
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes 
  kafka: 
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest 
    container_name: kafka 
    ports: 
      - "9092:9092" 
    environment: 
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes 
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092 
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

And I am using Python to pull Twitter Data which is then sent to a Kafka topic as shown in the code below

```
from sys import api_version
import tweepy
import configparser
import time

from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer
from datetime import datetime

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('twitter.cfg')
consumer_key = config["AUTH"]["twitter_api_key"]
consumer_secret=config["AUTH"]["twitter_api_secret"]
access_token=config["AUTH"]["twitter_api_access_token"]
access_token_secret=config["AUTH"]["twitter_api_access_secret"]
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', api_version='0.11.5')
topic_name = 'worldcup'


def normalize_timestamp(time):
    time_value = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
    return (time_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S'))


def get_twitter_data():
    res = api.search_tweets("QATAR WORLD CUP OR WORLD CUP 2022")
    # print(res)
    for i in res:
        record = ''
        record += str(i.user.id_str)
        record += ";"
        record += str(normalize_timestamp(str(i.created_at)))
        record += ";"
        record += str(i.user.followers_count)
        record += ";"
        record += str(i.user.location)
        record += ";"
        record += str(i.user.favourites_count)
        record += ";"
        record += str(i.retweet_count)
        record += ";"
        producer.send(topic_name,str.encode(record))

  
        

get_twitter_data()
def schedule_work(interval: int):
    counter = 1
    while True:
        get_twitter_data()
        print(f"Sending data to Kafka, #{counter}")
        counter += 1 
        time.sleep(interval)

schedule_work(60 * 0.1)
```

I am able to print out the messages from Twitter API but when I try to consume the same from the topic *worldcup* using Spark I get Results not generated error.My assumption is that the messages are most likely not getting written to the Kafka topic.

Here's the Spark code

```
package snowflake

// import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,SaveMode,SparkSession}
import java.util.UUID

case class TwitterData(user_id: Long, created_at: String, num_followers: Long, location: String, num_favourites: Long,num_retweets: Long)

object StreamHandler {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hi there Tito!!")

        val spark = SparkSession.builder
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("StreamHandler")
        .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._

        // subscribe to the topic  worldcup 
        val inputStreamDF = spark
            .readStream
            .format("kafka") // org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "worldcup")
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
            .load()
                
        inputStreamDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]
        println("We are here !!!", "=>",inputStreamDF.printSchema())


        var sfOptions = Map(
            "sfURL" -> "https://gjnedoz-dmb37080.snowflakecomputing.com",
            "sfAccount" -> "dmb37080",
            "sfUser" -> "<username>",
            "sfPassword" -> "<password>",
            "sfDatabase" -> "TWITTER",
            "sfSchema" -> "PUBLIC",
            "sfRole" -> "ACCOUNTADMIN"
        )

        // val SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

        // write data to table
        val query = inputStreamDF.writeStream
            .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
            .foreachBatch{(batchDF:DataFrame, batchID: Long) => 
            batchDF.write
                .format("console")
                .options(sfOptions) 
                .option("dbtable", "TWITTER")
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save()
            }
            .outputMode("update")
            .start()
        
        query.awaitTermination()

    }

}
```

Logging the messages to the console results in this
[image]

Comment: 1) call producer.flush() after sending the data 2) Please show your Spark code as the problem could be there 3) You could simply use a Python kafka consumer to check

Comment: I have tried what you said and on printing producer.flush() I get None. So the issue is actually the fact that the producer is not able to send messages to the topic @OneCricketeer

Comment: The flush function doesn't return anything. It's meant to clear the producer buffer to actually "send" _to the broker_

Comment: should the kafka topic be created outside the python script?@OneCricketeer

Comment: That doesn't really matter. You can use KafkaAdmin client - https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.create_topics Can you please show the Spark code?

Comment: So is Spark a requirement? [Snowflake has a Kafka Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html) and there is one for [Twitter](https://github.com/Eneco/kafka-connect-twitter) as well

Comment: as per the project yes, I want to use Spark specifically to handle concerns relating to data manipulation/transformations. I want Kafka to only handle the pulling of the data from the API

Comment: You're using Python to poll from the API, not Kafka. As pointed out, Kafka Connect will work, too. Regardless, as mentioned in the first comment, you can use several solutions to check that data is actually in the broker. Including `docker exec` into the container and running `kafka-console-consumer`

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is true, my python script is actually writing to the topic and I can see the messages. The problem is at the level where I am using the Spark Consumer

Comment: Well, your Spark code is trying to read `worldcup2022` topic. Your Python code is writing to just `worldcup`... These need to be the same

Comment: that is not the most recent code. The recent one reads worldcup

Comment: 1) Please [edit] with your latest code rather than a link to your repo. 2) To create a [mcve], if you replace the snowflake code with `.format("console")`, you still get nothing?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have made the edits as suggested

Comment: Seems Spark can clearly consume the data... I don't have experience with Snowflake to really help further.

Comment: yeah, no worries. I will find some snowflake resources to complete this. Thanks